# How to find exact word with regex in an input String in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a list which I have defined in the spring configuration file as follows:-

```
<bean id="LatinExpressions" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="sourceList">
            <list>
            <value>ad lib\.</value>
            <value>ad libitum</value>
            <value>ca</value>
            <value>ca\.</value>
            <value>circa</value>
            <value>cet\. par\.</value>
            <value>ceteris paribus</value>
            <value>cf\.</value>
            <value>e\.g\.</value>
            <value>i\.e\.</value>
            <value>in vacuo</value>
            <value>in situ</value>
            <value>in vitro</value>
            <value>in vivo</value>
            <value>inter alia</value>
            <value>versus</value>
            <value>vice versa</value>
            <value>vide infra</value>
            <value>vide supra</value>
            <value>viz\.</value>
            <value>vs</value>
            <value>vs\.</value>
            <value>versus</value>
            <value>in priori</value>
            <value>etc\.</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My role is to scan an input for these elements in the list and count the occurrences if they are in italics or roman. For this I have written a pattern that works for almost every but some cases. Below is the method that I have written:-

```
private String maintainRomanOrItalicConsistencyInArticle(String currentLine){

        int latinromanOcurrenceinContent=0;
        int latinitalicOccurenceinContent=0;

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("latinexpressions.xml");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> latinExpressions = (List<String>)ctx.getBean("LatinExpressions");

        for(String latinexp : latinExpressions){

            Pattern findRomanItalics = Pattern.compile("((<em>)?)\\b"+ latinexp+"(,|\\s){0,}(\\b)?((</em>)?)");
            Matcher findRomanItalicsMatcher = findRomanItalics.matcher(currentLine);
            while(findRomanItalicsMatcher.find()){

                if(findRomanItalicsMatcher.group(1)!=null && findRomanItalicsMatcher.group(5)!=null){
                    latinitalicOccurenceinContent+=1;
                }
                else{
                    latinromanOcurrenceinContent +=1;
                }
            }

        }

        if(latinromanOcurrenceinContent>latinitalicOccurenceinContent){
            System.out.println("latinromanOcurrenceinContent:::" + latinromanOcurrenceinContent);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("latinitalicOccurenceinContent::" +latinitalicOccurenceinContent);
        }

        return currentLine;

    }
```

Input for which I am testing is:= `"<p>For example try this <em>ad libitum</em>, <em>circa</em>, <em>paribus</em>are latin expressions.The following list also contains some latin expressions:-<em>ad lib.,</em>inter alia,<em>vide infra,</em>vide infra<em>in priori,</em></p> cater. This is ca, ad libitum;`

My problem is that my pattern is also finding `cater` as follows:-

[image]

I only need to find ca not cater or car or cab.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: EPP screenshot! Yes! A mighty weapon. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have specified in your regular expression that space or ',' has 0 or more occurrences. The leads to "cater" being matched. What you need is `{1,}` so that only the complete will be matched, as a word will be terminated with a punctuation. You might also want to replace `(,|\\s)` with `(,|\\s|\\.)`.

Comment: FYI: `{0,}` is the same as `*`, and `{1,}` is the same as `+`, and the latter versions are usually used.